# Converting 15 minutes interval usage data in pivot form to 60 minutes format

Tags: python, pandas

[image: This is my 15 Minute interval file sample distributed over 24 hrs]

I want to convert this to hourly format like:

```
df['1:00'] = df['0:15'] + df['0:30'] + df['0:45'] + df['1:00']
```

Also, i do not want to create extra duplicate columns.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#convert non time values to MultiIndex and sorting times columns
df1 = df.set_index(['Account','Date']).sort_index(axis=1)
#create groups by previous values of ends with :00
g = df1.columns.str.endswith(':00')[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
#aggregate sum
df2 = df1.groupby(g, axis=1).sum().add_suffix(':00').reset_index()
```